# Disable filename color changing based on lint/sonar in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

It is possible that my color scheme is not helping, but if you look at the attached image, you can see that `FuelPriceServiceBase.java` has "1 problem" and `GasBuddyFuelPriceService.java` has been modified (git). The rest of the files that have no problems and no changes are white.

I don't mind the filename changing colors on git changes, but is there a way to disable the filename color change for "issues"? I want to keep the number, but it doesn't need to change colors. At a glance, I think it's a changed file (git).

[image]

Comment: FWIW, I've changed my theme and the color differential is better. But I'd still just like it to not change colors.

Comment: Look at the `Explorer > Decorations: Color` setting.  Disable it.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative could be modifying the theme in your user settings.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme

I found this useful for some color contrast problems with my current almost perfect theme, and I couldn't find a comprehensive guide or documentation of every property, so my advice is either searching better than I did or see the source code of some themes, to find the correct property. Intellisense also helps, a lot.